# Second derivative in Tensorflow 2.0

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, tensorflow2.0, derivative

I am trying to calculate the second derivative of a simple vector function of a scalar variable `f(x) = (x,x^2,x^3)` using TF 2.3 with `tf.GradientTape`.

```
def f_ab(x):
    return x, x** 2, x** 3

import tensorflow as tf
in1 = tf.cast(tf.convert_to_tensor(tf.Variable([-1,3,0,6]))[:,None],tf.float64)
with tf.GradientTape(persistent=True) as tape2:
    tape2.watch(in1)
    with tf.GradientTape(persistent=True) as tape:
        tape.watch(in1)
        f1,f2,f3 = f_ab(in1)
    df1 = tape.gradient(f1, in1)
    df2 = tape.gradient(f2, in1)
    df3 = tape.gradient(f3, in1)

d2f1_dx2 = tape2.gradient(df1, in1)
d2f2_dx2 = tape2.gradient(df2, in1)
d2f3_dx2 = tape2.gradient(df3, in1)
```

for some reason, only the last two derivative are correct while the first, `d2f1_dx2`, turned out to be `None`.

When I changed `f_ab` to

```
def f_ab(x):
    return x** 1, x** 2, x**3
```

I got `d2f1_dx2 = <tf.Tensor: shape=(1, 4), dtype=float64, numpy=array([[-0.,  0., nan,  0.]])>`
which is "almost" the correct result.

only when I changed `f_ab` to

```
def f_ab(inputs_train):
    return tf.math.log(tf.math.exp(x) ), x** 2, x**3
```

I got the correct result: `d2f1_dx2  = <tf.Tensor: shape=(1, 4), dtype=float64, numpy=array([[0., 0., 0., 0.]])>`

Has anyone encountered this problem before? why is the straight forward way gives `None`?

Comment: This look indeed like a weird behaviour to me. Consider maybe filling an [issue on github](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues).

Answer (score 1):

I think it's because the first derivative of `x` is a constant. So by the time you compute the second derivative `Y` and `f1` are unrelated to each other since `f1` is a constant.

In Tensorflow `.gradient()` method default to `None` if there is no deffirentiable path in the graph between the 2 variables.

```
gradient(
    target, sources, output_gradients=None,
    unconnected_gradients=tf.UnconnectedGradients.NONE
)
```

[see Tensorflow doc](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/GradientTape#gradient)

You can change this argument by `0` instead of `None` and you should get the expected result for the derivative of `constant`.

Comment: No, the derivative of a constant should be zero

Comment: @BennyK, I know, not sure what you are referring to.

Comment: @BennyK, my explanation still stands, I don't understand how this invalidate my answer.

Comment: The derivative of constant vector should be vector of zeros, not None. I did not use gradient but gradientTape

Comment: @BennyK, you're doing `df1 = tape.gradient(f1, in1)` so you are using the gradient method. Now, what's happening is that gradient method default to `None` if there is no link between the two variables you are trying to differentiate. I agree that it should be `0` but what they put by default into `TF`is `None`. No you can change this behavior as I explain in my answer.

Comment: you can try by yourself that the first derivative of a constant vector is just vector of zeros